# Angular 2+ ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property ''" of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I've seen the same issue here but I tried a few solutions and I couldn't figure this out.

I am receiving the data from a JSON file and printing the values out using a service. The issue is I can see errors in the console like

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

It's Angular 2+.

See the code below:

iberpagetop.component.ts

```
export class IberPageTopComponent implements OnInit {
location: any[];  

constructor(private _locationService: LocationService, private translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('en'); 
}

switchLanguage(language: string) {
     this.translate.use(language);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this._locationService.getLocationData()
        .subscribe(data => this.location = data)

}
```

IberpageTop.html

```
<table class="">            
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><h3>DOÑA BENITA</h3></td>
          <td> <p><span translate>Business</span> {{ location[0].business }}</p></td>
          <td><p><span translate>Sub-Region</span> {{ location[0].subRegion }}</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p><span translate>Power</span> {{ location[0].power }}</p></td>              
          <td><p><span translate>Country</span> {{ location[0].country }}</p></td>
          <td><p><span translate>Maint. Region</span> {{ location[0].maintRegion }}</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td><p><span translate>Last updated</span> {{ location[0].lastUpdate }}</p></td>
          <td><p><span translate>Region</span> {{ location[0].region }}</p></td>
          <td><p><span translate>Main Area</span> {{ location[0].mainArea }}</p></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

locations.json

```
    [{
    "field": "DOÑA BENITA",
    "power": "32MW",
    "lastUpdate": "03/12/2018",
    "business": "ESP",
    "country": "SPAIN",
    "region": "ANDALUCIA",
    "subRegion": "CÁDIZ",
    "maintRegion": "SUR",
    "mainArea": "CÁDIZ"
}]
```

locations.ts (interface)

```
    export interface ILocation {
    field: string,
    power: string,
    lastUpdate: Date,
    business: string,
    country: string,
    region: string,
    subRegion: string,
    maintRegion: string,
    mainArea: string
}
```

location.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ILocation } from '../location';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class LocationService {

    private _url: string = "/assets/data/locations.json";


    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getLocationData(): Observable<ILocation[]> {
        return this.http.get<ILocation[]>(this._url);
    }
}
```

I'll appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `<table class="" *ngIf="location">`

Comment: It basically says that your service returns empty data. Check your file location and log the result of your call to be sure.

Comment: I used ngIf and it worked!!!Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

you should be use this to handle this kind of error. In all cases where you used this `location[0]?.<YOUR_KEY>` instead of `location[0].<YOUR_KEY>` to handle error in html page.

Comment: What´s the benefit of it?. Could you explain it deeper or give me and example?. Thanks

Comment: @Timba this `location[0]?.bussines` means it checked the `location` has value or not. if `location` has some value then it will show data otherwise it will show you blank value.

Comment: I get you!!! thanks